# Is it necessary to say both surat Al-fil and Quraysh in Salat to count as one Rukat?

Tags: salat, ruku

I've read in a few places that in order to say either surat Al-Fil or surat Quraysh in salat both must be said in order for the salah to be valid as these surahs are very closley linked. So one would say Al Fatha, then go onto say Al-Fil then would proceed to say Quraysh (with the bismallah for each surat) before one can proceed to ruku.   Is this true or is saying one or the other enough to proceed to ruku? Let me clarify, this is per rukat and not per salah.  So Al-Fil is to be said, then Quraysh before ruku then on the second rukat you can choose another other sura (excluding Al-Fil and Al Quraysh)

Comment: Who ever told you this should give a proof. The standard (recommendation) of most madhhabs is to recite a surah per raka'a except there's something else in the practice of the prophet. Further you may also find [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30669/can-we-recite-two-or-more-surahs-in-one-rakat-when-praying) helpful.

Comment: These are my references: http://en.wikishia.net/view/Sura_al-Fil  and:  https://www.al-islam.org/organizations/AalimNetwork/msg00059.html    however I believe they are not sufficient enough and only one of them is required (Al-Fil or Al-Quraysh) in order to continue onto ruku and then onto the next rukat in which I can then say a completely different surah. Please let me know if you think these references are enough.

Comment: Well you should better make clear which view you are looking for a shi'a or sunni view. As the links in your comments are providing are Shi'a sites.

Comment: My apologies, I am not looking for a Shi'a point of view at all - In fact I am looking for a Sunni point of view only.  I was just observing random sites as a result of my innocence in wanting an answer. Thank you.